# Changing between Java8 and Java7 Environments

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to change between Java7 and Java 8 environments.  I created the following new environment variables:

```
JAVA7_HOME - java 7 location
JAVA8_HOME - java 8 location
JAVA_HOME
```

I then set JAVA_HOME to be %JAVA8_HOME% or %JAVA7_HOME%.  In path I have

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;REST OF PATH
```

It seems no matter what I set JAVA_HOME to it will not change the outcome of java -version, even for new sessions.

How can we have two separate java environments while easily changing between them?  I've tried setting everything to the correct paths, that includes:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment JAVA_HOME
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment CurrentVersion
```

and even changing symlinks to point to the version we want.  We've create batch scripts to do it all, we've create powershell/,net to do it and then broadcast, tried setting it all and restarting explorer..  It seems impossible to switch between 7 and 8.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: If you are using a 32bit JRE on 64bit Windows then you need to modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment  "CurrentVersion"

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that changing environment variables via commandline is not permanent for some reason. You'll have to set the new value via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the following:

1. Put both the jdk8 and the jdk7 in your path (put the one you want as "default" first).
2. Look up `java.exe` and `javac.exe` in the jdk8 bin/ directory. Copy the executables under the name `java8.exe` and `javac8.exe`.
3. Do the same in the jdk7 bin/ directory, and copy the binaries to `java7.exe` and `javac7.exe`.

Now you can call java/javac, java7/javac7 and java8/javac8.
(I am not sure why anybody would need JAVA_HOME, I never set it.)
The other excutables like jar.exe and so on will be taken from the default jdk (the one first in the path), this is ok, since your JAR files will be the same no matter which jar.exe made them.

Then go on to configure the applications you need, like eclipse.

Hopefully, also your build tool can be told which executables to use. If not, it will use the default.

This way, you can also realize crazy configurations. For example, suppose you want jdk7 as default, but want to always use the java8 `javadoc`. Then simply rename the `javadoc.exe` from jdk7, for example to `javadoc-dontuse.exe`. This way, when you type `javadoc.exe` or some application calls it, it will not find it in the (default) jdk7 and continue to search in the jdk8 bin.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  Maybe.   Windows doesnt seem to be able to handle one path variable pointing to another path variable.  That is it doesnt seem to like the fact that Path is pointing to `%JAVA_HOME%` and that `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to `%JAVA7_HOME%`.  As soon as I change `%JAVA7-HOME%` and `%JAVA8_HOME%` to be a physical directory, its happy.